# How to update FastListTemplate main based on the type of chart selected

Tags: panel, holoviews

My use case is pretty generic;

Based on a `Select` widget value from `FastListTemplate` sidebar, I want to display the content in the `template.main` area. Also, on the landing page, I am already displaying an image and some text. So `on_click` or `param.watch` of the Select button should generate charts and replace the existing `template.main`.

I tried replacing it, however, once the template is rendered I don't see it changing when I select a different value in the selector.

Please suggest or point me to any resources that can help me here, many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template can not be rendered again, but we'll have to wrap the content in a `Column` or `Row` and update the content inside the `Column` or `Row`.

```
append_col = pn.Column(old_chart)
template.main.apend(append_col)
```

and to update it

```
append_col[0] = new_chart
```